# Diophantine equation $x^2 + 6(y+1)^2 = (y+2)^3$

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, maximal-and-prime-ideals

I'm revising for exams and I've got stuck on an algebraic number theory question. The equation I'm trying to solve is
$$
x^2  -2 = y^3,
$$
and I was told to rewrite it as 
$$
x^2 + 6(y+1)^2 = (y+2)^3.
$$
Then I was told to show there exist integers $u,v$ such that 
$$
u^2 + 6v^2 = y+2 \text{ and } x +(y+1)\sqrt{-6} = (u+v\sqrt{-6})^3.
$$
I tried factoring the equation in ideals as
$$
\big( x + \sqrt{-6}(y+1)\big)\big( x - \sqrt{-6}(y+1)\big) = \big(y+2 \big)^3,
$$
and I've been told for $K= \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-6})$ the only units are $\pm 1$ and the class number is $2$. But I can't show the two ideals on the left are coprime, so I'd really appreciate if someone could explain this to me. Thanks!

Comment: If $(x + \sqrt{-6})$ splits, its conjugate splits too. Since the class number is 2, principal ideals can only split into 2 prime ideals. Then the right hand side factors into either 4 prime ideals or stays inert as 2 prime ideals. The right hand side similarly factors into 6 prime ideals or stays inert as 3 prime ideals. Does this help?

Comment: Replace prime with prime non-principal ideals in the above comment.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not quite sure I understand how this helps. So on the LHS we have 2 principal ideals or 4 non-principal ideals and on the RHS either 3 principal or 6 non-principal ideals? How does this help find the $u,v$?

Comment: @asvin any ideas?

Comment: Brute force doesn't give me anything for $(x,y) < (12420219,206361)$ and beyond.

Comment: That doesn't sound implausible, the questions are usually of the form `show there are no solutions to the equation...', but in this case the questions asks to find all solutions, and I wouldn't be surprised if there were none.

Comment: @HandeBruijn What about $(x,y) = (1,-1)$? (according to [WolframAlpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integer%20solutions%20of%20x%5E2%20%2D%202%20%3D%3D%20y%5E3) this is the only solution, though)

Comment: @A.P.: Uhm, well, if someone has excluded the negative numbers ..

Comment: The bounty runs out in just over half a day if anyone has any ideas?

Comment: No one's pointed out that $x$ and $y$ have to be odd. So whatever you're doing; maybe this will help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I figured this out for myself anyway, so I thought I'd write it up here.

So we're trying to show first that the ideals 
$$
\left( x + \sqrt{-6}(y+1) \right) \text{ and } \left( x - \sqrt{-6}(y+1) \right)
$$
are coprime. So suppose there is some prime ideal $P$ dividing both of the ideals, then $2\sqrt{-6}(y+1) \in P$. Then we get
$$
\left( 2\sqrt{-6}(y+1) \right) \subseteq P \text{, and so } P \mid \left(2\sqrt{-6}(y+1)\right).
$$
Since $P$ is prime we can then deduce that either 
$$
P \mid (2), \text{ } P \mid\left(\sqrt{-6} \right) \text{ or } P \mid (y+1).
$$
Suppose the last case is true, then since
$$
\left( x + \sqrt{-6}(y+1) \right)\left( x - \sqrt{-6}(y+1) \right) = (y+2)^3,
$$
$P$ also divides $(y+2)^3$, and so divides $(y+2)$. Then we have that $(y+2)-(y+1) = 1 \in P$, which contradicts that $P$ is a prime ideal.

Next suppose that $P$ divides $(\sqrt{-6})$ or $(2)$. Using Dedekind's theorem (I'm not going to write out all the details seeing as this was a question I asked), if we define $P_2 = (2, \sqrt{-6})$, $P_3 = (3, \sqrt{-6})$ then we have
$$
(2) = P_2^2, \text{ and } (\sqrt{-6}) = P_2P_3.
$$
First suppose $P_2$ divides both ideals, then $P_2 \mid( y+2)^3$, so $P_2 \mid (y+2)$, as $P_2$ is prime (again by Dedekind's theorem). Then by taking norms we get 
$$
2 \mid y^2 + 4y + 4, \text{ in the integers}.
$$
Thus $y = 2y'$ and similarly from the initial equation $x^2 - 2 = y^3$ we get $x = 2x'$ for some $x',y'$ in the integers. Then we get the equation
$$
2x'^2 - 1 = 4y'^2.
$$
This equation clearly has no integer solutions upon reducing modulo $2$, so we get a contradiction and $P_2$ cannot divide both the ideals on the left hand side of the equation.

So lastly we need to consider $P_3$. Similarly we get, by taking norms, that 
$$
3 \mid (y+2)^2,
$$
and this gives ys that $y$ is congruent to $1 \pmod{3}$. Then considering the equation $x^2 - 2 = y^3$ gives that $x$ is congruent to $0$ modulo $3$.  Substituting in $x = 3x'$ and $y=3y' + 1$ gives, upon expanding and dividing by $3$,
$$
3x'^2 - 1 = 9y'^3 + 9y'^2 + 3y',
$$
which again has no solutions after reducing modulo 3. So $p_3$ cannot divide both the ideals either and so $\left( x + \sqrt{-6}(y+1) \right)$ and $\left( x - \sqrt{-6}(y+1) \right)$ are coprime ideals.

Since we have unique factorisation for ideals in a ring of integers we can then write
$$
\left( x + \sqrt{-6}(y+1) \right) = I_1^3 \text{ and } \left( x - \sqrt{-6}(y+1) \right) = I_2^3
$$
for some ideals $I_1$ and $I_2$ of $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-6}] = \mathcal{O}_K$ where $K = \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-6})$. Since the class number is $2$ and $I_2$ cubes to a principal ideal we must have that $I_1$ is principal, thus 
$$
\left( x + \sqrt{-6}(y+1) \right) = (\alpha)^3 = (\alpha^3),
$$
for some $\alpha$ in $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-6}]$. Since the only units in $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-6}]$ are $\pm1$ we then get 
$$
x + \sqrt{-6}(y+1) = \pm \alpha^3 = (u +\sqrt{-6}v)^3,
$$
for some $u,v$ in $\mathbb{Z}$. Then we can immediately see that
$$
x - \sqrt{-6}(y+1) = (u - \sqrt{-6}v)^3,
$$
and so $(y+2)^3 = (u^2 + 6v^2)^3$. This then gives us
$$
y+2 = u^2 + 6v^2,
$$
which was the end of the question I asked, but I'm going to write out the rest of the solution to the diophantine equation anyway, for completeness.

We can then expand $x + \sqrt{-6}(y+1) = (u + \sqrt{-6}v)^3$ and equate the coefficients of $1$ and $\sqrt{-6}$ to get
$$
x = u^3 -18uv^2, \text{ and } y +1 = 3u^2v - 6v^3.
$$
Then as $y+ 2  = u^2 + 6v^2$ we have
$$
u^2 + 6v^2 = 1 + 3u^2v -6v^3,
$$
which we can rearrange to 
$$
u^2 = \frac{ 1-6v^2(1+ v)}{1-3v}, \text{ or } 9u^2 = \frac{45v^2(1+v) - 9}{3v-1}.
$$
Just by polynomial division this gives
$$
9u^2 = 18v^2 + 18v + 8 - \frac{1}{3v-1},
$$
and so $9u^2$ is an integer only if $\frac{1}{3v-1}$ is an integer which is true only if $v = 0$. Thus in particular $u$ is an integer only if $v = 0$. Then $v = 0$ gives us that $u^2 = 1 $ by substituting into the above equation. Thus, $y = -1$ and so $x^2 = 1$ and the only integer solutions to the equation are
$$
(x,y) = (\pm1, -1).
$$